# Proof of derivatives of exponential function

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I am learning Calculus and I ran into the proof regarding the exponential derivative, I haven't quite understood it though, could you guys please help me out with that? The proof goes like that:

$$y = a^x$$
$$ln(y) = ln(a^x)$$
$$ln(y) = x(ln(a))$$

Here comes the part I haven't gotten yet, why is y'/y = lna?

$$ \frac{y'}{y} = lna$$
$$y´= lna(y)$$
$$y´= ln(a)(a^x)$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Second line should be $\ln y = \ln (a^x)$, not $\ln (a^2)$

Comment: @dust05, tks! I got it right now ;)

Comment: Use $\log(a^b)=b\log a$ and differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\ln (y) = \ln (a^x)\\
\ln (y) = x \ln (a)\\
y´/y = \ln a
$$

Where from 2nd to 3rd, you differentiate with respect to x on both sides.

Derivative of $\ln x$ is $1/x$. So using the chain rule, derivative of $\ln y$ is $1/y * dy/dx$. Rearrange and use prime notation for derivative and you get $y´/y$

Comment: @AHusian, tks for your reply! I wonder how you transform ln(y) into y´/y... I mean, I don't get this notation/representation, would be so kind as to explain to me? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

When you go from $ln(y)=x(ln(a))$, we differentiate both sides. For the left side:

$$\frac{d}{dx}ln(y)$$
Which by the chain rule yields:

$$\frac{d}{dx}y\times\frac{d}{dy}ln(y)$$
$$=y'\times\frac{1}{y}$$
$$=\frac{y'}{y}$$

For the right-hand side, the derivative of $ln(y)=x(ln(a))$ is $ln(a)$ (which can easily be confirmed) and you can then solve what $y'$ is.

Comment: Thanks, man! I understood it now! You are the best! ;)

Comment: You are very welcome!